# How to Parse a incoming email and send the parsed data as POST request to a endpoint on localhost?

Tags: servlets, sendgrid, postmark

I have an email for my application, and I want to parse the incoming emails coming to the mail and send the parsed data as a POST Request to an endpoint in localhost(i.e..a servlet). I want to send it to a servlet because I have coded the servlet to send a reply mail for that parsed data.
I found that there are some services for parsing incoming emails like mailparser.io,postmark,sendgrid. Will these services work for localhost? or is there any other ways or services for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite open, but I try to answer it as best as possible:

Yes, this is possible with SendGrid's "Inbound Parse" feature. For this, you need to register the webhook (SendGrid uses the name "Inbound Parse" here) in the SendGrid console and point to your server, which could run locally. In that case you might need to use a tunnel via [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/).

If this sounds right for you, please refer to this [webinar recording](https://app.experiencewelcome.com/events/60uKG4/stages/jrfb1g) (starting at 2:03:00) to dive deeper or fork this [sample code repository](https://github.com/IObert/sendgrid-ts-in-10-min)